# String Aggregation in Oracle: Multiple Rows into Single Column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, string-concatenation

hi I have following function for string aggregation in oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION STRING_AGGREGATE(i_query VARCHAR2,
i_seperator VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',')
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  l_return CLOB:='';
  l_temp VARCHAR(32000);
  TYPE r_cursor is REF CURSOR;
  rc r_cursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN rc FOR i_query;
  LOOP
    FETCH rc
    INTO L_TEMP;
    EXIT WHEN RC%NOTFOUND;
    l_return:=l_return||L_TEMP||i_seperator;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN RTRIM(l_return,i_seperator);
END;
```

when i call this function it show like this

```
SELECT STRING_AGGREGATE('select ename from emp') ENAMES FROM DUAL;

ENAMES
---------------------------
SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES,MARTIN,BLAKE,CLARK,SCOTT,KING,TURNER,ADAMS,JAMES,FORD,MILLER
```

this function working good here but when i call this function with multiple column with space it give me error here is my query

```
SELECT STRING_AGGREGATE('select ename||' Job is '||Job from emp') ENAMES FROM DUAL;
```

i want to get result

```
smith job is clerk,allen job is accountatnt,ward job is programmer etc..
```

please guide me how to achieve this

Comment: Pleas provide precise information about the error - error code, error message etc.

Comment: error message is ora:00907 missing right parenthesis

Comment: The errormessage is somewhat misleading - there is no apostrophes after `ename` and before `Job from emp` - try this query: `SELECT STRING_AGGREGATE('select ename '||' Job is '|| 'Job from emp') ENAMES FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the single-quotes

```
SELECT STRING_AGGREGATE('select ename||'' Job is ''||Job from emp') ENAMES FROM DUAL;
```

You can try out out how you pass the string to the function like this

```
SELECT 'select ename||'' Job is ''||Job from emp' FROM DUAL;
```

which gives you

```
select ename||' Job is '||Job from emp
```

See the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/23283

(By the way. There is a new feature `LISTAGG` since Oracle 11g which you may also want to have a look at.)

Comment: now this query give me same error         `SELECT DEPTNO,STRING_AGGREGATE('SELECT ENAME FROM  EMP WHERE DEPTNO='||DEPTNO,',' and job='Programmer')ENAME FROM EMP
GROUP BY DEPTNO
ORDER BY 1 `

Comment: Every time you have a `'` between the first and last `'` you must double the `'` like this `''`. Okay? This means "escaping". Also I think there is something wrong about the `DEPTNO`. I think it should read: `SELECT DEPTNO,STRING_AGGREGATE('SELECT ENAME FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO='||DEPTNO||' and job=''Programmer''')ENAME FROM EMP GROUP BY DEPTNO ORDER BY 1`

Comment: hol i try to check your query but it give me error missing right parenthesis

Comment: this query work for me `SELECT DEPTNO,STRING_AGGREGATE('SELECT ENAME FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO='||DEPTNO,',')ENAME FROM EMP GROUP BY DEPTNO ORDER BY 1`   but when i use  and job=''Programmer'' its not working

Comment: Maybe it is a uppercase / lowercase problem. Can you try `lower(job) = ''programmer''` ?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would offer the solution using Oracle's delivered function, `LISTAGG`.

Run:

```
select listagg(ename || ' is a ' || job, ', ')
within group (order by job, ename)
from   emp
where  job in ('MANAGER','ANALYST','CLERK');
```

You will get:

> FORD is a ANALYST, SCOTT is a ANALYST, ADAMS is a CLERK, JAMES is a CLERK, MILLER is a CLERK, SMITH is a CLERK, BLAKE is a MANAGER, CLARK is a MANAGER, JONES is a MANAGER