# Map Comma Separated ID field into Comma Separated Name field in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, csv

I have one table, UAC that holds group IDs for a particular user.  I need to merge some of this info into another table, but instead of inserting the IDs, I want to insert the names for these groups, found in table UGM.  The IDs in UAC that are comma separated map to the PK ids of UGM.

Tried to merge on id, but because it's comma separated it won't work.

Essentially, I want to construct a column that looks like this:

`Admin, Teacher, Student` from a column that looks like this `1, 2, 3`

Comment: Storing comma-separated values in a relational database column is a terrible design.  Propagating that terrible-ness to a new table is worse.

Comment: Don't particularly have a choice.  @JustinCave.  It's a company chosen design pattern and updating it would break half the systems

Comment: Split CSV into table, join and aggregate back. All the answers are on this site, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38371989/2778710) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19474028/2778710)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **NOT** store the values in comma-separated lists; instead store the values in a separate table and `JOIN` them together.

If you have to use a list (**DON'T**) then split the table using a recursive sub-query factoring clause and simple string functions and then join with the other table and aggregate back into a list:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (group_ids, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT group_ids,
         1,
         INSTR(group_ids, ', ', 1)
  FROM   uac
UNION ALL
  SELECT group_ids,
         epos + 2,
         INSTR(group_ids, ', ', epos + 2)
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY group_ids SET order_id
SELECT LISTAGG(u.value, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY spos) AS value_ids
FROM   rsqfc r
       INNER JOIN ugm u
       ON TO_CHAR(u.id) = CASE epos
                          WHEN 0
                          THEN SUBSTR(group_ids, spos)
                          ELSE SUBSTR(group_ids, spos, epos - spos)
                          END
GROUP BY r.group_ids
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE uac (group_ids) AS
SELECT '1, 2, 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2, 1, 4, 5' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ugm (id, value) AS
SELECT 1, 'Admin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Teacher' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Student' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'XXXXX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'YYYYY' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE_IDS |
| --- |
| Admin, Teacher, Student |
| Teacher, Admin, XXXXX, YYYYY |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5dx0VqR2)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  It ain't pretty but here's what I got

```
SELECT LISTAGG(group, ',')
from (
    WITH DATA AS (
        SELECT group_id as str
        FROM personnel
        WHERE id = '123'
    )
    SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
    FROM DATA CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL 
) join groups on str = id;
```

Comment: This will "work" if you filter the table so you are only processing a single row (but regular expressions will be slower than simple string functions, even if they are less to type). Don't use this to process multiple rows; you will find that you get exponentially increasing numbers of duplicate rows.

Comment: Yep.  Ran into this issue.  Ended up yelling at my company to change the underlying architecture since we have 150k rows in the DB and gave up on this.  After pointing this out, as well they seemed to deal with it.